# How can I "cache" rxjs lettable operators and reuse them in multiple `.pipe()` calls without breaking TypeScript's type checking

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, webstorm, rxjs5, angular5

(FYI. The context of this is an Angular 5 app, however the circumstance is not particular to Angular per se)

I have a few operators that use a lot in the same way in various places. To repeat less code, I stored them in a base class:

```
export class ComponentBase {

  protected unSubscriber$: Subject<any> = new Subject();
  protected endWhenDestroyed = takeUntil(this.unSubscriber$);
  protected filterOutNulls = filter(x => notNullOrUndefined(x));

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.unSubscriber$.next();
    this.unSubscriber$.complete();
  }
...
```

Later, other components inherit from the class above and simply reuse those operators:

```
class SomeClass extends ComponentBase {
...
    someObservable$
      .pipe(this.filterOutNulls, this.endWhenDestroyed)
      .subscribe((y) => ...) // type of `y` is lost by typescript
...
```

If I use the operators normally like

```
class SomeClass extends ComponentBase {
...
    someObservable$
      .pipe(filter(x => !!x), takeUntil(this.unSubscriber$))
      .subscribe((y) => ...)
...
```

then, TypeScript understands that the type of `y` (on the subscribe) is the one from the source observable. However, when I use my *cached* operators, the type is lost and I need to do `.subscribe((y: WhatEverType) => ...` for it to compile and the editor (IntelliJ, in my case) to stop complaining.

Now, this code below makes it all work...

```
    const getOp = <T>(): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<T> => {
      return filter(x => !!x);
    };
...
    someObservable$
      .pipe(getOp<TheType>())
      .subscribe((y) => ...)
```

However, my question is if there's a way for the types to continue to flow as they do when the operator functions are declared inline without having to manually cast the type neither in the subscriber nor the cached operator as shown above.

In any case, I'd appreciate any other elegant alternatives of doing this.

Thanks indeed

Comment: You want to use generica for that to type your function generically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hadn't realized that by using the exact solution I posted at the end of the question, it works fine even without manually casting the type on the usage of the "cached" operator function.

So, instead of doing as a originally posted:

```
const myFilter = filter(x => !!x);
const getOp = <T>(): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<T> => {
  return myFilter;
};

someObservable$
  .pipe(getOp<TheType>())
  .subscribe((y) => ...)
```

It is sufficient to do

```
someObservable$
  .pipe(getOp()) // no need to specify <TheType> here
  .subscribe((y) => ...)
```

And the type flows well :)